# What is the relationship between a $\Pi_1^1$ sentence and the "canonically-associated tree"?

Tags: set-theory

I am reading this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07952

On page 7 in the second paragraph of section 3.2 there is

> This is a true $\Pi_1^1$ assertion in the collapse extension $V[g_0]$, which is therefore equivalent to the well-foundedness of the canonically associated tree, which has some rank $λ_0$ in $V[g_0]$; by homogeneity this does
> not depend on the generic filter.

What is this "canonically associated tree"? Since the paper does not give a definition or reference anywhere, I assume this is some common knowledge.

Comment: $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi^1_1$ are two very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See e.g. Jech "Set theory", 3rd millenium ed, page 483-488;
or see Moschovakis "Descriptive set theory". Also see Shoenfield absoluteness.